# How to focus opener window in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Focus opener window not working in Chrome...

Example 1.

```
popunder=window.open('http://google.com','asdf','width=800,height=800');
popunder.blur();
popunder.opener.window.focus();
```

Example 2.

```
popunder=window.open('http://google.com','asdf','width=800,height=800');
popunder.blur();

x = popunder.window.open('about:blank');
x.close();

popunder.opener.window.focus();
```

Example 3.

```
popunder=window.open('http://google.com','asdf','width=800,height=800');
popunder.blur();
window.focus();
```

Example ... and so on.

Does anyone know a solution that works?

Comment: Don't create a popunder. Nobody likes them.

Comment: I know, but no one asks me. Chief says "Do it!". :/

Comment: @rjanjic have you tried using `https`?

Answer (score 9):

The only solution that currently works in Chrome is this code inside new window:

```
$(".closeBtn").click( function(e) 
{
    window.open("",window.opener.name);
});
```

Unfortunately the solution only works under two conditions:

- `window.opener` has to have it's name set on document load (`window.name="WhateverName";`)
- `window.open()` is called on user click

Comment: Works well, thx! Also if you are in a frame (I share your pain) of new window use this code to focus opener window: window.open("", window.top.opener.name);

Comment: It looks like you can name the opener...
        var randomName = 'a' + Math.random();
        window.opener.name = randomName;
        window.open('', randomName);

But even this may not always work. :(

Comment: Can somebody else confirm this? If it's a fact I'll remove the answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm also working on this issue, currently the latest Canary build 26, breaks all of the hacks that I know about. I know there are still some sites that are working around this, but can't figure out how.

There is [jquery popunder](https://github.com/hpbuniat/jquery-popunder), but only if you have jquery available.