# window.close() not working (originally opened via JS/JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, instagram-api, window.open

I am using an Instagram API and the only way to log out is through the link https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/ which will redirect the user to the Instagram page (if someone knows an alternative method please let me know).  However, I want to redirect the user to my own page.  (I had previously tried the methods to do so in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991753/instagram-api-user-logout) post.  The `img`/`iframe` will append and redirect the user to my page, but the user was still signed in.)
This is the code that I am currently using:

```
$('.logout').on("click", function () {
     window.open('https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/'); 
     window.close();
     window.location.replace("logout-page.html");
}
```

The Instagram page successfully opens in a new tab and signs the user out, while my page redirects to the logout page, but I want the Instagram logout page to close on its own after its opens.  Other people were saying that `window.close()` works only when it was opened via script using `window.open()`, which I am doing and it still does not work.  I have also tried `window.open("", self).close()` and other variations of that and those did not work for me either.

Comment: "I want the Instagram logout page to close" So, you want close the newly-opened window? Store it in a variable, and use that variable as a context to `close()`. Currently you're trying to close the current window, i.e. the window which executes the script.

Comment: I have tried that also and it did not work either

Comment: ?? Try with a [delay](https://jsfiddle.net/t4zfe8so/).

Comment: The new tab still doesn't close

Comment: Do you get it closed on my fiddle? If you don't, please add `console.log(popup)` immediately before the close call. Then check the console, if you'll find `null` or `undefined`, your browser options are blocking the closing.

Comment: FYI, the fiddle I've linked above seems to open and close a tab in FF, Edge and IE, but in Chrome it won't be closed. Unfortenately I'm not that familiar with Chrome, that I could say, how to allow it to also close a tab.

Answer (score 1):

To close the opened window, you have to define it as an object.

A `setTimeout` delay to close will allow it to fully open the url.
Adjust the delay if needed... But 1 second should work.

```
myWindow = window.open('https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/');

setTimeout(function(){
    myWindow.close();
},1000);
```

**EDIT**
It seems that it is not possible to "hide" a popup...
I found a way is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15363515/2159528), but it requires to add a script in the popup page...

With the script above, the popup opens as a new tab... And stays opened only 1 second. That was the best I could tell... Until I found [this other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28422498/2159528) that you may try.

Comment: I have tried those and they didn't work, unfortunately

Comment: I updated my answer with a delay... Maybe you need to keep the window openned long enought to load the page. ;)

Comment: `left=-1000px,top=-1000px` don't seem to be working, as the window is still visible

Comment: Edited again... Have a look.

Comment: I have already tried the second link, which successfully appends the `img`/`iframe` and redirects the user without opening any new windows/tabs, but fails to log the user out.

Answer (score 1):

`window.open` returns an object of the new windows that has been opened. To modify this new window you have to use the returned object like:

```
new_window = window.open("url");
new_window.close();
```

Anyway this isn't a good solution because you don't know whether the new opened window has loaded the page successfully or has finished loading it.

I would recommend to just open the logout page in a new window and redirect the current page like this:

```
my_window = window.open("url", "Window-Name", "height=200,width=200");
document.location = "your_url"; //redirects the current page...`
```

Comment: Great, it works! Do you know if there is a way to open the new window behind the original one though? So that the user doesn't see a window suddenly pop up and disappear.

Comment: Yes! read here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp You can position the new window out of the viewport ... Like `left="-1000px", top="-1000px"`

Comment: Actually apparently `left` and `top` are not allowed to be negative.  I tried it in my application and it doesn't throw an error, but the window is still visible.  Do you know of an alternative method or a way around that?

Comment: @user2302052- but in my case i returned document null on that case

Answer (score 0):

just open the url in hidden iframe that is appended in DOM somewhere. Below is jQuery code:

```
$('#content').append('<div style="display:none"><iframe src="https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/" width="0" height="0"></iframe></div>');
```

This is how I have implemented in https://www.picosdash.com to logout and allow multiple account login in app, works great.

Comment: That's what the other post that I linked above suggested, which didn't work for me

Comment: It trows this error in console: `Refused to display 'https://www.instagram.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`... Maybe not in all browsers... But in Chrome.

Comment: i know, but it does logout, the error is thrown cause that url later redirects to just "instagram.com" and that is blocked with 'X-frame-Options', but the logout url opens and does the job of logout

Comment: Yes there are various successful methods to simply logout by allowing the Instagram redirect.  I could also use a brute force method that adds an anchor tag and sets it's href to the the logout link; however, the main point of my question was to redirect to my own page.  I have checked/retried the mentioned method several times and with different variations and they have all failed to work.  I have solved the issue using the code that Luke posted, but thank you for your input.